# AngularJS apply filter by default

Tags: angularjs

Im creating angularJS app with a list of items. I've implemented filtering of the list successfully, but I can't find out the way how to apply it by default. What I mean is that I want to display filtered list by default and users to be able to see the full list if they want.

I've tried selecting option by default but this doesn't trigger filtering at all despite it is selected.

my filter looks like this:

```
<select ng-model="query.status" ng-click="setItems()" class="form-control">
        <option value="">All tasks</option>
        <option value="0" ng-selected="true" selected="selected">Todo</option>
        <option value="1">Done</option>
</select>
```

setItems() Function is used for pagination only so it doesn't have any affect on filtering itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is `query.status` responsible of filtering your list ? 
In that case init it to the value you want the list to be filtered by.